# AWS Codedeploy deployments failing intermittently with no logging information and no deployment id wise directory getting created

Tags: jenkins, aws-code-deploy

We have a Jenkins triggered build setup, which has AWS code deploy setup in post build action. The first deployment of the day happened as follows -

- Kept showed in progress in the AWS codedeploy console indefinitely, even after 10 minutes.
- Jenkins timeout happening resulting the following last status 
  Following are the last log lines from deployment logs -

  Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 0,InProgress: 3,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0}
  Exceeded maximum polling time of 500000 milliseconds.
  Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 0,InProgress: 3,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0}
  Deployment did not succeed. Final status: InProgress
- I had to manually stop the deployment from AWS console.
- Our custom generated log file showed the script corresponding to the afterInstall step executed till the end.
- Deployment ID wise directory created in designated place `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/3dfdc563-66c5-47a0-98f8-01605d25a6e9/` and following was the last line from the `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log` file (which are not fatal errors and are not expected to keep the build hanging) -

  [2017-08-10 07:10:22.484] [d-C2A5P270O][stderr]ls: cannot access tests/hiphop_errors.txt: No such file or
   directory
  [2017-08-10 07:10:27.511] [d-C2A5P270O][stderr]cat: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/3dfdc563-66c5-4
  7a0-98f8-01605d25a6e9/d-C2A5P270O/deployment-archive/tests/dummy_nginx_access_logs.txt: No such file or directory

Following are screenshots from AWS code deploy console - 
[image]

Details against a single instance show no details about the error - 
[image]

Then I did a `dos2unix` of all the hook files (files which get executed at the various deployment steps, i.e. afterInstall, beforeInstall etc) in the build server, just to be sure, because I had faced similar issues earlier after copy-pasting windows files/code. After this, took two more builds, and now I see the following -

- Deployment failed on all the instances. AWS code deploy console showed failed against all the instances, with no details -

[image]

- No deployment-id specific directories created at designated place, as in previous case. No deployment logs created at all.

I am clueless again due to code deploy behaving weirdly. Yesterday, we had observed a similar issue of log files not generating. A reinstall of the codedeploy agent was done and then deployment logs were creating fine. But, how many times should we do a new install blindly?

**Update**

Adding contents of `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log` file for the case where the deployment kept showing in progress indefinitely, as pointed out in the answer by @EmptyArsenal (I do not notice anything wrong in the log) -

```
2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.065601 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:377703961998:instance/i-e551e37d")

2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.044413 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTEvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTE6Mzc3NzAzOTYxOTk4OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1XNDFCV0tLN08iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6Mzc3NzAzOTYxOTk4Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktZTU1MWUzN2QiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFmdGVySW5zdGFsbCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.2017-08-21 11:13:47 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1983)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.027061 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-1/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-1:377703961998:deployment/d-W41BWKK7O",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:377703961998:instance/i-e551e37d")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the hosts never start executing lifecycle events, it's almost always the case where the agent isn't install, it's not running, or permissions are not set up properly. You should only have to install the agent once, so I'm not sure why you had to reinstall. Perhaps the agent died, and it just wasn't running (though it should restart on its own).

I would check out logs at `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`. Those are the agent logs and are not deployment specific. If the agent is crashing, you should see information there.

As for the deployment specific error your seeing, it looks like a script error to me. Either the files you're trying to access don't exist or you don't have proper permissions to interact with them. You can fix that in your appspec. If those are failing anywhere, you might want to do a deployment without running those commands to validate that the errors really aren't fatal.

Comment: Added the contents of the log file you pointed out. Added in Update to my question body.

Comment: I did a set of deployments today again. First did a deployment without any change to any script - it stuck at "in progress" as mentioned in the first part of my question. I stopped it forcefully and then commented out the part responsible for showing the file access errors, just to make sure it was not failing because of that. That deployment onwards did not log anything (case 2 of my observation in question details). It appears like I can do one deployment per day, which hangs and thereafter no deployment succeeds. Really weird.

Comment: If you look at the history of your deployments, can you see successful deployments to the exact same host, even if over multiple days? One possibility is that your deployment is making some change to the host that is causing deployments to fail. If you're using AutoScaling groups, the host might be getting recycled daily, causing a new host to spin up and avoiding the race condition. If that's the case, I would look at your scripts or anything making changes on the box that might be messing things up.